# TypeError: deriv() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, numpy

I'm getting the above error. I understand in principle what it means, but can't really see how it applies to my code

```
#project starts here
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import pi
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def deriv(cond,t):
    for q in range (0,N):
        i=6*q
        dydt[i]=cond[i+3]
        dydt[i+1]=cond[i+4]
        dydt[i+2]=cond[i+5]
        r=sqrt((cond[i])**2 +(cond[i+1])**2 +(cond[i+2])**2)
        dydt[i+3]=-G*M*cond[i]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+4]=-G*M*cond[i+1]/(r**3)
        dydt[i+5]=-G*M*cond[i+2]/(r**3)
    return dydt

G=1
M=1
N=12
vmag=((G*M)/(2))**(0.5)
theta = np.linspace(0,2*pi,N)
x=2*np.cos(theta)
y=2*np.sin(theta)
vx=-vmag*np.sin(theta)
vy=vmag*np.cos(theta)
z=np.zeros(N)
vz=np.zeros(N)
t=np.linspace(0,30,100)

cond=list(item for group in zip(x,y,z,vx,vy,vz) for item in group)
sln=odeint(deriv, cond, t, args=(G,M))
```

Any ideas where it is coming from? I feel like I have given the correct number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending 4 arguments to `deriv`. Per the [odeint docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), you have a function `deriv` whose first two arguments must be `y` and `t`. When you call `odeint(deriv,cond,t,...)` the `cond` and `t` are automatically sent as the first two arguments to `deriv`. All you need to do is to make `deriv(cond,t,G,M)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look documantation for odeint [1], you will see that your fucntion to call in oneint must be in form **func(y, t0, ...)**. So when you call **odeint(deriv, cond, t, args=(G,M))** it actually call your function as **deriv(cond,t,G,m)**. But your function takes just 2 argument.

[1] http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html